# Question mark and colon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators, conditional-operator

I came across the following line

```
hsb.s = max != 0 ? 255 * delta / max : 0;
```

What do the `?` and `:` mean in this context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 377, accepted):

It is called the [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (which is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)).

It has the form of: `condition` ? `value-if-true` : `value-if-false`
Think of the `?` as "then" and `:` as "else".

Your code is equivalent to

```
if (max != 0)
  hsb.s = 255 * delta / max;
else
  hsb.s = 0;
```

Comment: "?" isn't the ternary operator; "? :" is the ternary operator. Talking about "?" as the ternary operator is like talking about Abbott without Costello, Laurel without Hardy, Cheech without Chong....

Comment: Ok, ok... now I'm using an ambiguous pronoun, happy? :)

Comment: To be pedantic, it's **a** ternary operator, which happens to be the only one in most programming languages.  Any operator that works on 3 parts is a ternary operator, just like `addition` is a binary operator that operates on the preceding and following expressions (e.g. 1+2 the plus operates on 1 and 2), or negation is a unary operator (e.g. -x where the value of x is negated).

Comment: @Davy8: And this one can be called the [tag:conditional-operator] to be specific.

Comment: What if you wanted to check two conditions?

Comment: @ThanosDodd - Use nesting, or use `if`/`else if`/`else` instead.

Answer (score 40):

Properly parenthesized for clarity, it is

```
hsb.s = (max != 0) ? (255 * delta / max) : 0;
```

meaning return either

- `255*delta/max` if max != 0
- `0` if max == 0

Answer (score 8):

```
hsb.s = max != 0 ? 255 * delta / max : 0;
```

`?` is a ternary operator. It works like an `if` in conjunction with the `:`

`!=` means not equals

So, the long form of this line would be

```
if (max != 0) { //if max is not zero
  hsb.s = 255 * delta / max;
} else {
  hsb.s = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is probably a bit clearer when written with brackets as follows:

```
hsb.s = (max != 0) ? (255 * delta / max) : 0;
```

What it does is evaluate the part in the first brackets. If the result is true then the part after the ? and before the : is returned. If it is false, then what follows the : is returned.

Answer (score 1):

?: is a short-hand condition for `else {}` and `if(){}` problems.
So your code is interchangeable to this:

```
if(max != 0){
       hsb.s = 225 * delta / max
}
else {
       hsb.s = 0
}
```

[MDN - Conditional (Ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), it is essentially a basic `if` condition check that can be written to execute an operation if the block of code within the ternary operation is valid, otherwise default to a fallback.

A ternary operation is written in the following syntax:

```
condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse
```

- `condition` An expression whose value is used as a condition.
- `exprIfTrue` An expression which is evaluated if the condition evaluates to a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value (one which equals or can be converted to true).
- `exprIfFalse` An expression which is executed if the condition is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (that is, has a value which can be converted to false).

#### Example

Take the given function below which should return the string `Yes` if the number provided to the function is even, otherwise return `No`.

```js
function isEven(num) {
    return (num % 2 == 0) ? "Yes" : "No";
}

console.log("2: " + isEven(2));
console.log("3: " + isEven(3));
```

#### Explanation

The operation above broken down:

- `(num % 2 == 0)` | This is a simple `if` statement condition to check if the expression within the brackets is true.
- `? "Yes"` If the operation is true, the string literal given is automatically returned as a result of this execution.
- `: "No"` This is the `else` clause in this operation, if the condition is not met then `No` is returned.

Answer (score -1):

`? :` isn't this the ternary operator?

`var x= expression ? true:false`

Comment: That's one example of its use, but there's actually a shorter version of your statement, for those cases where you just want TRUE / FALSE: If 'expression' was just some variable with a number or string in it, "var x = !!expression" will make it into a boolean result.

Answer (score -4):

Be careful with this.  A -1 evaluates to true although -1 != true and -1 != false.  Trust me, I've seen it happen.

so

-1 ? "true side" : "false side"

evaluates to "true side"

Comment: "In JavaScript, a **truthy** value is a value that is considered  true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN)." This is why -1 is evaluated as true. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)