# javascript to objective-c conversion

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I know nothing about javascript and need help interpreting the following:

```
{
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch(max){
      case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
      case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
      case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain what this means so I can code an equivalent in Objective-C ?

Thank you!

or to make my question even more to the point. could you please translate (to human language) the following line for me ?

```
s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
```

Comment: Equivalent C (and thus Objective-C) code would look pretty much identical. What part do you not understand?

Comment: the second line specifically .... s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);  thank you.

Comment: `switch`/`case` with variable cases would be incompatible with C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
```

the `expression ? value1 : value2` operator evaluates the `expression` and, if it's true, returns `value1`, else returns `value2`.
so in that particular case, it will evaluate `l > 0.5`, if that's true it'll set `s` to `d / (2 - max - min)`, else it'll set `s` to `d / (max + min)`

---

**EDIT in response to comment:**

I don't really know a lot of Javascript at all, but as for the `switch` statement, it seems to be using variable cases. That's not allowed in Objective-C (or C, for that matter). But it seems to be trying to find which of the `r`, `g` or `b` variables is equal to the `max` variable...

In Objective-C (or C, or C++) a `switch` statement can only use constant case values, like this:

```
switch (myVariable)
{
    case 0:
        //do something if myVariable == 0
        break;
    case 1:
        //do something if myVariable == 1
        break;
    case 2:
        //do something if myVariable == 2
        break;
}
```

I'm gonna take a guess here and say that in javascript with variable cases, it would probably be equivalent to something like

```
if (max == r)
    h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
else if (max == g)
    h = (b - r) / d + 2;
else if (max == b)
    h = (r - g) / d + 4;
```

if anyone who knows more about javascript could confirm that for us, it would be great.

Comment: yeah, that's what I ended up doing exactly. thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very straightforward, all you have to do is change `var` to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a fragment from an algorithm to assign new RGB colors to something. Can't tell without any info about the values max, min. d is probably "distance".

var s is assigned something with a ternary ?: operator, but s is not used again in the block-

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it means that whomever you inherited that code from needs to learn how to name variables properly.

Comment: Just passing by, but can't help commenting: looks like this code converts RGB into HSL, which means that variables named h, s and l actually make perfect sense. And the purpose of the 'd' variable is perfectly clear from the first assignment (when you see d = max - min, you know that it stands for 'delta' or 'distance'). So I wouldn't say the names are bad.