# What does this syntax mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

I've seen this around a few times but I never knew what it meant. What is the name of it and how does it work?

Here is the example I saw:

```
input.checked = input.type == "radio" ? true : false;
```

Comment: are you sure that there should be 2 equals signs here: `input.checked == input.type`?

Comment: I hope you don't see this kind of redundant and unparenthesised code that often...

Comment: Is this the *exact* code? It looks a bit suspect... do you have a URL to it?

Comment: The code should really be changed to `input.checked = (input.type === "radio");`

Comment: Yes. That was my fault. I didn't mean to use the extra equal sign for the first statement.

Comment: Google this: "ternary operator"

Comment: @Peter: Doesn't even need the `()`. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. I know, I think it's more readable that way.

Comment: @Peter: Quite possibly, yeah. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>That example has an extra `=` in it, I think you meant:</s>

```
input.checked = input.type == "radio" ? true : false;
```

*(It's fixed now.)*

It assigns `true` to `input.checked` if `input.type == "radio"`, or `false` if it doesn't.

That

```
expression ? trueResult : falseResult
```

...is called the *conditional operator* (or sometimes, the "ternary" operator — technically, it's just *a* ternary operator, e.g., an operator that takes three operands). More in [Section 11.12](http://es5.github.com/#x11.12) in the spec.

In this case, there's absolutely no point in using the conditional operator, because the result of the equivalence expression is `true` or `false` anyway, so it could be written just:

```
input.checked = input.type == "radio";
```

...but there are lots of places where the conditional operator is useful. For instance, suppose you wanted to assign `1` or `2` to `x` depending on whether `y` was 42:

```
x = y == 42 ? 1 : 2;
```

You can think of the `?` as asking a yes-or-no question, with what follows it being the "yes" answer, and what follows the `:` being the "no" answer.

Comment: Does the "ternary" operator require a falseResult value?? Can I leave it out if I want?

Comment: @David: The value of the condition expression (the expression before the `?`) will be coerced to a boolean if it isn't a boolean based on the usual JavaScript rules (just like the expression you use in an `if` statement). I'm not sure what you mean by "can you leave it out." If you're assigning `true` or `false` as in your question, then as I said, there's no need for the conditional operator -- just assign the result directly to `checked`. But if you want to assign something other than `true` or `false`, the conditional operator is a handy way to do that in some situations.

Comment: @David: Oh, sorry, I see what you mean. Yes, the false part is required when using the conditional operator. You have to have something between the `:` and the end of the expression. Otherwise use an `if` or JavaScript's [curiously powerful `||` and `&&` operators](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's easier to understand like this:

```
input.checked = (input.type == "radio")? true : false;
```

It's basically an **if else**. If the expression is true then **input.checked** will be set to the first value, else the second value.

**[edit]**

As a note, in JavaScript, you should always use '===' instead of '==' when evaluating strings to check type equality as well.

Comment: Not quite - note the double == for the input.checked. It's not an assignment, it's a comparison.

Comment: Ah, missed that, I have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Jon, I'm pretty sure the OP had a typo.

Comment: You should suggest the use of `===` instead of `==` in Javascript.

Comment: Does the "ternary" operator require a false result value?? Can I leave it out if I want?

Comment: @PeterO Good point. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ternary expression. It is a shorthand for:

```
if (input.type == "radio") {
    input.checked = true;
} else {
    input.checked = false;
}
```

However, there is redundancy in this particular example. It could have been simply written as:

```
input.checked = input.type == "radio";
```

Comment: Does the ternary operator require a false result value? Can I leave it out if I want??

Comment: @David Yes (to your first question). No (to your second).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the first `==` is `=`?

It looks like [ternary operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)  (short else-if structure)

Comment: Does the ternary operator require a false result value?? Can I leave it out if I want??

Comment: In javascript is required. You can't do something like `a = ( x == 3) ? 5;` But you can do in such a way: `a = ( x==3 ) ? 5 : a`. It means in a false result case, `a` will be equals to `a`