# Can someone please explain this syntax in Javascript - " type = type || 'fx' "

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this construct (x = x || y) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean)

I've seen this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me). And some similar code on other places that I can't recall.

1. `time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;`
2. `type = type || "fx";`

What does it mean?

I don't understand *a)* at all but I *think* I understand *b)* like this:

If `type` is false then `type` will be equal to `"fx"` otherwise `type` will equal whatever it was before.

I'm not sure, but perhaps I'm wrong.

What is this syntax called? Conditional variable? :P I tried Googling for an answer but have no idea what to use in my query.

Comment: You should probably also have a look at [Question mark in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript).

Comment: @Felix Kling I appologize, I see that it is somewhat similar, but as I stated in my original question, I did not know how to structure an effictive query with which to search, the terms I searched yielded no results. But thanks for pointing to those links it also helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**a)**

```
time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;
```

is synonym for

```
if (jQuery.fx) {
    if (jQuery.fx.speeds[time]) {
        time = jQuery.fx.speeds[time];
    }
}
```

which is almost the same as

**b)**

```
type = type || "fx";
```

is synonym for

```
if (!type) {
   type = "fx";
}
```

Simply it checks if `type` is not `false`, `null`, `undefined`. If yes, `type` is being filled with `fx`

Comment: thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 2):

For A, what we're doing is a shortcut for an if-else statement. The stuff before the question mark refers to the if statement, the next element is the "then" statement, and the final part is the "else" statement.

```
var action = my_status == 'hungry' ? 'eat' : 'do not eat';
```

In this case, it would translate into something like this:

```
if (my_status == 'hungry')
   action = 'eat';
else
   action = 'do not eat';
```

For B, double pipes (||) mean "or". What we're evaluating here is a Boolean value based on whether one OR the other is true.

```
var not_hungry = ate_lunch || full;
```

If either ate_lunch OR full is true, the not_hungry is also true.

You can do the same thing with double ampersands (&&) which mean AND.

```
var single = nerdy && cocky;
```

If nerdy AND cocky are true, then single is also true. If only one of those is true, then the statement resolves to false (since both must be true for single to be true).

Hope that helps. :)

Edit (h/t Phrogz):
It's worth noting that || and && in JavaScript don't only operate upon and evaluate to a Boolean value, but rather are "guard" operators that test for 'truthiness' and evaluate to one of the two operands. (

Comment: Good answer, but you should amend it to point out that `||` and `&&` in JavaScript don't only operate upon and evaluate to a Boolean value, but rather are "guard" operators that test for 'truthiness' and evaluate to one of the two operands.

Comment: Excellent point, Phrogz.

Answer (score 1):

```
time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;
```

Can be written as:

```
if (jQuery.fx) {
   if (jQuery.fx.speeds[time]){
       time =  jQuery.fx.speeds[time];
   } 
}
```

In this case the ternary operation (`? :`) is redundant. The statement returns `time` if JQuery.fx.speeds[time] doesn't exist - so it returns itself.

More general: `somevar = a || b` is called *short circuit evaluation*. Basically it's a short way of writing

```
if (a) {
  somevar = a;
} else {
  somevar = b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also answers my questions :)

Answer (score 0):

a) Set time to `jQuery.fx.speeds[time]` if and only if `jQuery.fx` and `jQuery.fx.speeds[time]` exists:

```
if(jQuery.fx && jQuery.fx.speeds[time])
    time = jQuery.fx.speeds[time];
```

b) Your description is correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right about what it does. It's known as [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation. It does something similar to C's [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C).

Comment: think this is more like a comment not an answer...

Comment: @evilone: The question is in two parts: What it does and what it's called. Did I miss one?

Comment: @nmichaels thanks, it actually answers the 2nd part of my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a ternary operator

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator

I was trying to link to the first result here...

https://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=4&gs_id=1j&xhr=t&q=wiki+inline+if&

Comment: Do you care to edit your link?

Comment: Well, that isn't the link I wanted to show. There is actually a wiki page to '?:' but I can't link to it. 3 down votes? Seems a bit harsh.

Answer (score 0):

a.) is structured using ternary operator, in simple term think of

```
time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;
```

as equivalent to:

```
time = if(jQuery.fx){ jQuery.fx.speeds[time]; } else { time : time; }
```

b.) you are correct in that type will be defined if type is already defined, otherwise it'll default to "fx". However, I'm not sure if there's a technical name for it except it is the logical expression for OR

Comment: Maybe "equivalent to the following pseudo code that is not valid JavaScript syntax but perhaps you can understand what I'm trying to illustrator" :)