# Not understand how this checking-empty-form-value-code works (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I came across [this page](http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter1.html) and reading the example codes. I don't understand how the following line works in the the codes. How did it assign the value "\nlogin:" to the "error" variable when the form value is empty?

The line of code:

```
error+=f.login.value==''?'\nlogin':'';
```

The whole example code is under **"2. Javascript is an enhancement, not a secure functionality"**.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means:

```
if(f.login.value == '')
    error += '\nlogin'; 
else
    error += '';
```

The `?:` syntax is called the [ternary (or conditional) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), and works like an inline if/else statement.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I saw the ? in the codes but I could not comprehend that it was the ternary operator, because it was so compact! (And the single quotes confused me too) Now I see, thanks again!