# Are these two variable settings equal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, javascriptcore

I have been wondering that are these two ways of performing variable setting always giving me the same results:

```
var t = test ? test : 0
```

and

```
var t = test || 0
```

Because the latter is a bit faster way to do it than the first one and for now I have seen it working exactly the same but was just wondering is this just an illusion and is it possible that it will behave unexpectedly in some specific situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those examples are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The first is called the ternary operator and can also be used to evaluate an expression. See

[Question Mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript/1771805#1771805)