# javascript document.all and document.all.id_name stands for

Tags: javascript

i was going through a js file and land up on this statement 
`var dataobj=document.all? document.all.id_name : document.getElementById("id_name")`

what does this means?
like `?` is a macro in c++ for compact if else statement. but here in `js` what does it stands for?

```
function NewsScrollStart(){
dataobj=document.all? document.all.NewsDiv : document.getElementById("NewsDiv")
dataobj.style.top=topspace
setTimeout("HeightData()",( startdelay * 1000 ))
}
```

this was the actual function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.all` is mostly used in the old Microsoft IE versions which didn't support dom standards. 
The ?: syntax is a ternary operator and means exactly the same as it does in C++.

Answer (score 3):

`document.all` is a proprietary Microsoft API used to access elements in the DOM. It serves the same purpose as `getElementById` but predates it. You should only use `document.all` if you need to support very old versions of Internet Explorer (i.e. IE 4) which don't support the DOM 1 standard.

The `?:` syntax is a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript) and means exactly the same as it does in C++.