# Understanding JavaScript Syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have been tasked with re-writing some code for a client reservation form and I was hoping someone could explain the following syntax.  I know its basically like an if statement but the way it is set up is a little obscure to me since I am somewhat new to JavaScript:

```
testDate.setHours
(
    ampm.value=="AM"?
    (timestr[0]==12?0:timestr[0]=timestr[0]):
    (timestr[0]==12?12:timestr[0]=timestr[0]+12)
);
```

The whole reasoning behind this problem that I am working on is to take a value in for the reservation time.  It parses the string into an array where timestr[0] is the hour value.  Based on AM/PM and the value the user inputs, it will do its conversion to set the hours to military time.  I am not sure that this is even working correctly.

If someone could analyze this code, explain the syntax to me (?,:, etc.) and tell me if this is the appropriate way to convert the hours I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Dave

**EDIT :**

Also, would this be an identical way of writing it, just easier to understand:

```
if(ampm.value=="AM")
{
    if(timestr[0]==12)
    {
        timestr[0] = 0;
        testDate.setHours(timestr[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        testDate.setHours(timestr[0]);
    }
}
else
{
    if(timestr[0]==12)
    {
        testDate.setHours(timestr[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        timestr[0] = timestr[0] + 12;
        testDate.setHours(timestr[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up ternary operators

Comment: this is not a peculiar javascript syntax, anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Comment: While I was wondering the syntax, and this may be present in the post you included, I was also asking if the time conversion looks to be set up correctly.  Thank you for the other post though as this may provide extra insight into my syntax question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a ternary operator.

```
var answer = boolean ? response_1 : response 2;
```

is the same as writing:

```
if (boolean) {
    answer = response_1;
} else {
    answer = response_2;
}
```

In your case part of that, `timestr[0]==12?0:timestr[0]=timestr[0]` means, if `timestr[0]` is 12, then `0`, else `timestr[0]=timestr[0]`. That last bit, `timestr[0]=timestr[0]` is a weird way of just saying `timestr[0]`. It's likely an error.

Wrapping ternarys in more ternarys is often frowned upon as it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [ternary if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and you really shouldn't use it like this - the code becomes very difficult to read. I would refactor it to use regular if statements, the developers who come after you will thank you!

The syntax works like this:

```
var result = boolean_value ? true_result : false_result;
```