# issue when trying to use $(window).resize(function() inside a switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to capture the window size in certain case and depend of the width I apply a different left position using this code :

```
 case 'above':
        modal.css({
          'top': buttonPosition.top - modal.outerHeight() + scrollTop,
          'left': $(window).resize(function() { 
                      var i = $(this).width(); 
                      if (i > 735) { buttonPosition.left - 188;}
                      else {
                        buttonPosition.left - 100;
                      }
                    })
        });
        break;
```

but this don't seem to apply any thing whatever the width of the window the element still in the same position , but when i remove the `$(window).resize(function()` it works like so :

```
case 'above':
        modal.css({
          'top': buttonPosition.top - modal.outerHeight() + scrollTop,
          'left': buttonPosition.left - 188;
        });
        break;
```

but this is don't allow  me to change the left position depend on the window size , any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
case 'above':
        modal.css({
          'top': buttonPosition.top - modal.outerHeight() + scrollTop,
          'left': $(window).width() > 735 ? buttonPosition.left - 188 : buttonPosition.left - 100
        });
        break;
```

For info on the ? syntax see here: [Question Mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer as correct? Thanks :)