# GEO location TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of null

Tags: javascript, geolocation

On a new connection i get sometimes the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of null` and mostly it works correct!

How do i avoid this whenever its null so i will not get the error?

Error line is `var location = geo.country;`

```
        var ip =  socket.ip //socket.ip;
        var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);     
        var location = geo.country;
        console.log(location);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional:

```
var location = geo ? geo.country : "unknown";
```

The conditional operator is explained in detail here:

[Question Mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Comment: can you explain me what this do (I'm beginner)

Comment: I've added a link to a question that explains it.

Comment: @Inna I'm running on 127.0.0.1 for example. This ip address is in no way connected to a country, so Barmar'a answer simply assigns the country "unknown" to ip address (like 127.0.0.1) . Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are getting `null.country` which according to your code, means geo is returning `null`. That also means your geoip is not working. Do console.log() to check if your geoip is returning value or null.