# How this variable is going to do in this function:

Tags: javascript, function, datetime

I want to know about what exactly is being done with `variable a` in below function :

```
function c(a) {
    var b = new Date;
    return Math.round(b.getTime() / 1e3 + (a ? a : 0))
}
```

Code that needs clarity:

```
(a?a:0)
```

Just want to know what is the logic of highlighted text.

Comment: It is a ternary operator... if a is a truthy value then use that else pass 0

Comment: it's a rough way of making `a == 0` if null/false/undefined (falsey) passed in to function c ... may as well have been `(a || 0)`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript. There is more than enough documentation on that pattern already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is `undefined` or `false` or `null` or `NaN` it will return `0` else it will return value of `a`

Lets assume

```
var someVar = 23;

function c(a) {
    return a ? a : 0;  //Also true for negative values
}

c(someVar); //will return 23
```

And

```
 var someVar = -22;        
 c(someVar); //will return -22
```

And

```
 var someVar = false;        
 c(someVar); //will return 0
```

And

```
 var someVar;  //someVar is undefined       
 c(someVar); //will return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to use bold style, aren't you?

The statement x > 5 ? true : false is a shortened version of an if...else statement. You put the statement before the "?". The ":" separates the if and else part. If the statement is true, then the part before the : fires, if false, then the one after it. Because javascript likes to convert anything into booleans, the statement you have is the same as `if (a > 0) {  b = a } else { b =  0}`
If you want to know more about these statements, search for `ternary operators`

Answer (score 1):

these two lines

```
var b = new Date;
return Math.round(b.getTime() / 1e3 + (a ? a : 0))
```

can also be written as (for better readability)

```
var b = new Date;
var c = b.getTime() / 1e3 ; // 1e3 is 1000, so c is basically number of seconds since 1970

if ( !a ) //if a is either undefined, null or false
{
  a = 0;
}
return Math.round(c+a); //now c+a is adding these seconds to the paramter you have passed
```

So this function is basically passing the number of seconds since 1970 to the value you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

the "? : " is known as a ternary operator. It is a shortcut for an `if else`. For example, `var b = a ? a : 0` is equivalent to:

```
var b;
if(a){ 
   b = a;
}else{ 
   b = 0; 
}
```

Also, for the sake of clarity, your code misses () and ;. Here is a correct version:

```
function c(a) {
    var b = new Date();
    return Math.round(b.getTime() / 1e3 + (a ? a : 0));
}
```

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-to-use-the-ternary-operator-in-javascript) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a){
   return a;
}
else{
   return 0;
}
```