# What does it mean "isset($cs_theme_options['cs_default_page_layout']) ? $cs_theme_options['cs_default_page_layout'] : '';"

Tags: php

```
isset($cs_theme_options['cs_default_page_layout']) ? $cs_theme_options['cs_default_page_layout'] : '';
```

In above line there is "?" mark and also ":" mark, what does it mean between two variables? any one can describe it.

Comment: That is called a _ternary_operator_ with details in the docs http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the ternary operator. Which means a IF/ELSE on the same line : `(condition ? truePart : falsePart)`.

Though, this question was already asked here :
[Question Mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)