# What does (function() {})(); syntax work?

Tags: javascript

First question ever here. I'm a bit nervous to break the ice, please be indulgent I just finished the CodeAcademy JS lessons.

In the following code that I found to toggle some of my #element, I guess that it switches my class.property from its initial state to "block", and from "block" to its initial state. Correct me if I'm wrong. But if I'm not, can someone explain to me how does this is performed?

```
class.property === 'value' ? '' : 'value';
```

> [Question Mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript) - condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false

At this point I understand that ' ' is equal to 'none', it makes sense. Then it finally pass this property conditon value-if-true and value-if-false to my #element (which is trigged with some onclick(). But what if now I want that my function to also trigger some section position:?

I tried to add this, but it failed. I also don't understand why using (function() {})();

```
  (function (style) {
    style.display = style.display === 'fixed' ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
})(document.getElementById(section).style);
```

Here is the original code :

```
function toggledisplay(elementID) {
    (function (style) {
        style.display = style.display === 'block' ? '' : 'block';
    })(document.getElementById(elementID).style);
};
```

Comment: That's horrible code. It should have been just `var style = document.getElementById(elementID).style;`

Comment: Not certain what Question is? Does `js` at OP not return expected result?

Comment: What you're using is called a [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: @Arista A function declared like this `(function (){})();` is called an anonymous function and can only be called right where it is declared. For that reason functions declared like this almost always return some sort of object value to be used throughout the script. Generally I would stay away from using this type of function unless you are creating a js library like [jquery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: hi guys,  always a bit harsh to dissect codes at the beginings but very uselful, thank you all for your lights!

Answer (score 1):

`fixed` and `absolute` are [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) values not [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```js
function toggledisplay(elementID) {
  var style = document.getElementById(elementID).style;
  style.position = style.position === 'fixed' ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
};
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#mydiv {
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggledisplay('mydiv')">Toggle</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Note: There is no real need to have the IIFE function, you can simply use a variable to refer to the `style` property

Comment: Can you please remove that unnecessary function declaration inside the first function declaration. There is literally no reason to call an anonymous function like that and is a bad programming practice.

Comment: @AndrewBonsall yes, kept it only because OP had it