# Is JavaScript as HTML Attribute Bad Practice?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37289566/710887

I see this happening more and more often.

I was always taught to keep javascript, css, and html separate (with html linking to the sources/scripts of course).

Is using an Javascript in an HTML attribute (such as `onclick, onchange, etc:`) bad practice?

```html
<span id="valBox">25</span>
<input type="range" min="5" max="50" step="1" value="25" onchange="valBox.textContent = this.value">
```

Comment: They are allowed for the exact purpose of using them! If simple sure, but you're not storing state here, that's for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *wrong*, per se, but yes, it is seen as bad practice by the vast majority of people.

Good practice is to separate the HTML and Javascript as much as you can. It is the same concept as with CSS. Mixing up the HTML, CSS and Javascript in the same file can become unmanageable very quickly, and should be avoided, if at all possible.

Ideally, the two should be in separate files (`.html` and `.js` files), but separating them in the HTML is a good first step.

You can separate the two by using event listeners, like so:

```
<!-- The elements -->
<span id="valBox">25</span>
<input id="inputBox" type="range" min="5" max="50" step="1" value="25">

<script>
    // Grab the elements here
    var val = document.getElementById("valBox");
    var inp = document.getElementById("inputBox");

    // Add an event listener to the input element and
    // set the span value when it changes
    inp.addEventListener("change", function () {
        val.textContent = this.value;
    });
</script>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick#6348597) if you need to support IE<=9.

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, it is very bad practice, however, sometimes, while testing/doing a quick implementation, it is much faster:

```
<button onclick="alert('Hello World!');">Hey There!</button>
```

VS

```
<script>
  window.onload = function()
  {
      document.getElementById("button").onclick = function()
          {
              alert("Hello World!");
          }
  }
</script>
<button id="button">Hey There!</button>
```

Having said that, the latter is much preferable for debugging/code maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Each attribute is a new listener. The more attributes you have, the heavier.
Mixing JS and HTML is not considered good practice. Think of it as separation of concern. The markup is there to provide the client with a UI. JS's job (in a browser) is to enhance the user experience. They have to work together, but have different tasks. Hence, they should be treated as separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

It is messy and can be unmanageable, in that if you get errors or unexpected results you will have a harder time tracing the code that causes the error, meaning it is technically a bad practice. You could very easily replace the code you provided with a

```
<script>
    //Scripts
    ...        
    function MyMethodName(val){
        ...("#valbox").text = val;
    };
</script>
...
<span id="valBox">25</span>
<input type="range" min="5" max="50" step="1" value="25"
onchange="MyMethodName(this.value)">
```

or whatever is syntactically correct.

EDIT:
This is a non-inline equivalent using jQuery

```
<script>
    $('#inputID').change(function(){
        $('#valbox').text($('#inputID').val()); 
    });

<span id="valBox">25</span>
<input id="inputID" type="range" min="5" max="50" step="1" value="25">

</script>
```

Comment: That still has Javascript in the HTML onchange attribute (just like in the linked example), so I am not sure what the difference is.

Comment: The onChange attribute is a client side event that allows for a function or method to be called. This has technically been replaced with jQuery using a similar `$('#valbox').change();`, which is still technically an event that is just intercepted in a different way (i believe from the event log of the browser) that is not in the line of code.

 Both are valid and the inline method i described isn't "bad practice", it's just a bit outdated. the method you described where you perform operations inline IS considered bad practice.