# Different methods to return true or false

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference I have to take care by using one of these comparisons or are they completly identical:

```
return !!(foo == 'bar')

return (foo == 'bar') ? true : false;

if (foo == 'bar') return true;
else return false;
```

Comment: You missed the best option: `return foo === 'bar'`

Comment: Also: `return foo == "bar" && true || false`,  `return Boolean(foo == "bar");`, `return [false, true][Number(foo == "bar")];` or anything else you might want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1529630) and [Question Mark in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1771786/1529630)

Answer (score -1):

The better one (not included in the list) is

```
return foo === 'bar';
```

All expressions return the same result, but because of `==` or `===` operators return a boolean value you can simplify the expression and have a more readable code.