# Solving a time and day issue

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how this works. can someone explain it to me? Especially the variable name "prepand" which I've seen as "prepend" when I look it up. Also, what does the ? mean in (hour>12)?

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();
var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday 
","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
       console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
        var hour = today.getHours();
        var minute = today.getMinutes();
        var second = today.getSeconds();
        var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
        hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;

if (hour===0 && prepand===' PM ') 
{    
   if (minute===0 && second===0)
   {  
      hour=12;
      prepand=' Noon';
   }  
   else
   {  
      hour=12;
      prepand=' PM';
   }  
}

if (hour===0 && prepand===' AM ') 
{    
   if (minute===0 && second===0)
   {  
      hour=12;
      prepand=' Midnight';
   }  
   else
   {  
      hour=12;
      prepand=' AM';
   }  
}  

console.log("Current Time : "+hour + prepand + " : " + minute + " : " + second);
```

Comment: The question mark is part of a ternary statement.  `(conditional) ? true : false;` A variable name that is misspelled is probably due to a mistake in spelling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question Mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Comment: `var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";` This is a Ternary Conditional Operator. It is a really useful Conditional which in laymans means: If hour is greater than ofr equal to 12, set`prepand` to PM, if not set to AM.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

That is a basic code which gets the current date and tell you the day and time by manipulating the date. Check the comments corresponding to the lines.

> Prepand variable is used to add the AM/PM with the time

[Read here in details about Date](http://getMinutes()%20method%20returns%20the%20minutes%20in%20the%20specified%20date%20according%20to%20local%20time)

```js
var today = new Date(); //Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in time
var day = today.getDay(); // return the index of the day
var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday  ","Thursday","Friday ","Saturday "];
    console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
    var hour = today.getHours();// getHours() method returns the hour for the specified date
    var minute = today.getMinutes();//getMinutes() method returns the minutes in the specified date
    var second = today.getSeconds();
    var prepand = (hour >= 12) ? " PM " : " AM ";
    hour = (hour >= 12) ? hour - 12 : hour; //? is a part of ternary operator which will check if hour >=12 or not. If >=  then prepand in PM otherwise AM

    if (hour === 0 && prepand === ' PM ') {
      if (minute === 0 && second === 0) {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' Noon';
      } else {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' PM';
      }
    }

    if (hour === 0 && prepand === ' AM ') {
      if (minute === 0 && second === 0) {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' Midnight';
      } else {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' AM';
      }
    }


    console.log("Current Time : " + hour + prepand + " : " + minute + " : " +
      second);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
```

This translates to:

```
var prepand;
if (hour >= 12){
    prepand = "PM";
} else {
   prepand = "AM";
}
```

This writing is a shorthand expression called ternary. It is used to assign conditional values to variables in this case.