# What purpose do these elements serve in this JS function?

Tags: javascript

the [MDN page for the flatten() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatten) has this snippet of code

```
(function flattenDeep(arr1){
   return arr1.reduce((acc, val) =>
    Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
})(arr1);
```

What I'd like to know is

1. Why is the entire function encapsulated in `()`?
2. What does `(arr1)` after the function do?
3. What is the name for the `something ? doThis : orDoThis` algorithm?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once.  *Both* of these quesions have been asked here numerous times before.

Comment: And [Question mark and colon in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771786/4642212), [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). Don’t ask multiple questions per post.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Why is the entire function encapsulated in ()?

Because it's a *self-invoking* function or  an `Immediately-Invoked Function Expression`, or `IIFE` for short. It executes immediately after it’s created. A *self-invoking* expression is invoked (started) automatically, without being called.

> 2.What does (arr1) after the function do?

It's the parameter for your `self-invoking` function.

> 3.What is the name for the something ? doThis : orDoThis algorithm?

It's just [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).