# Undefined boolean in an object javascript

Tags: javascript, object, boolean, javascript-objects

I attempted the following task but i am stuck on defining a boolean:

> Define a function `getWalletFacts` that receives wallet, an object.
>
> `getWalletFacts` should return a sentence stating the wallet’s color and
> cash state.

My attempted code

```
const hascash = Boolean();

let wallet ={
    color:"",
    hascash:true||false,
    write: function(sentence){
        console.log(sentence);
    }
};
function getWalletFacts(wallet){
    let sentence= "my wallet is " + wallet.color+ " and  " + wallet.hascash; 
    return sentence;
}
```

whenever i check my answer it tells me that hascash is undefined i.e

```
    Expected: "My wallet is Black and has cash"
        Received: "my wallet is Black and  undefined"
```

from my understanding of the question hascash accepts a boolean

**Given example**

```
const wallet = {
    color: "Black",
    hasCash: true
};

getWalletFacts(wallet); // => 'My wallet is Black and has cash'

const wallet2 = {
    color: "Grey",
    hasCash: false
};

getWalletFacts(wallet2); // => 'My wallet is Grey and does not have cash'
```

Comment: How are you calling getWalletFacts?

Comment: `wallet.hascash` won't evaluate to 'has cash'; your sentence would read "My wallet is Black and true." Also, what is `const hascash = Boolean();` for? You don't reference it.

Comment: What's the point of `hascash:true||false`? That's the same as `hashcash: true`.

Comment: @mykaf Thanks for the feedback. So what should i do to make the sentence read "My wallet is Black and has cash"or "My wallet is Black and has no cash"

Comment: @James GetwalletFacts is called by the software when i submit my work ,the system check if i'm meeting the questions criteria.

Comment: @Barmar Ive been experimenting with different code so i'm not too sure. I've just started out learning javascript so i'm just getting familiar with it. 
Any suggestions on what i should do?

Comment: EIther `hascash: true` or `hascash: false` depending on what you want the value to be.

Comment: I suspect the intent of the problem is that the wallet should have a `cashAmount` property, not just a boolean. And the cash state is whether `cashAmount` is zero or non-zero.

Comment: @Barmar so i dont have a defined value. the system creates inputs and tests if the code will work with both true and false.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `hascash`, not `hasCash`? And I suspect `hasCash` should be a function that you call, not a property.

Comment: Please post the full question, as there's context missing here.

Comment: @Barmar I've added the missing given example at the bottom of the original post. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

It's `hasCash`, not `hascash` -- JavaScript is case-sensitive.

You also need a conditional to turn the `true/false` values into proper English.

```js
function getWalletFacts(wallet) {
  let sentence = "my wallet is " + wallet.color + " and " + (wallet.hasCash ? "has cash" : "does not have cash");
  return sentence;
}

const wallet = {
    color: "Black",
    hasCash: true
};

console.log(getWalletFacts(wallet)); // => 'My wallet is Black and has cash'

const wallet2 = {
    color: "Grey",
    hasCash: false
};

console.log(getWalletFacts(wallet2)); // => 'My wallet is Grey and does not have cash'
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the conditional to turn the true/false values into proper English

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWalletFacts(wallet) {
let money = " ";
if (wallet.hasCash === true) {
    money = "has cash";
}   else {
    money = "does not have cash";
}
let sentence = "My wallet is " + wallet.color + " and " + money;
return sentence;

}
```

Comment: The problem in the code of the user who asked the question is case sensitive of hasCash, your code is just a different style